# What's best practice to share one content page(node) with multiple sites on one Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I have two sites on single Umbraco CMS, for example, My Account page, System Activation page, shopping cart pages. I don't want to add same pages to each site I have.

I know that I can use those pages directly without creating them in content section, just by using the template name. For some reasons, I do need to create those pages in Content section but with no duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect candidate for [umbracoInternalRedirectId](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracointernalredirectid). On the dummy nodes, add a property with alias "umbracoInternalRedirectId" using a content picker data type.

You can then use the content picker to point to the node that contains the actual content. The URL will remain the same, but the content from the chosen node will be displayed.

Comment: This sounds very interesting, I will give it a go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I created a mobile site as a second site in Umbraco I added a content picker to the mobile pages.  The content editors would pick where they wanted the content to come from in the main site tree and I just had to do a quick lookup to get the appropriate page.

Perhaps that might work?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add a field to each document type, say a checkboxlist, that specified which of the sites (site a, site b, both) the page that is generated should be displayed on and then like the umbraconavihide field you could suppress stuff you don't want to see on a site by site basis.

If the doctype was inherited by all other doctypes then you would only need to do it once.

Obviously all of your templates (masterpages) would need to check this value in page_load (for example) and your navigation macros would also need modifying.

After writing that it all seems a bit excessive TBH.